# What is recommended way to tune the GC for an application which does not follow weak generational hypothesis?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

If I have an application

1. That does not follow the weak generational hypothesis, i.e newly allocated objects can stick around for long time, also these can be large. You could imagine a long running (5-10mins) processing that is happening.
2. Using reasonably large heaps (>16 GB)
3. Needs to be JVM 7 (can't use java8).

If I configure the Eden & Survivor spaces too large to accommodate the large temp (but sticking for > 10mins) objects, it might actually create longer pauses and it would also not guaranteed that these objects don't get tenured prematurely.

Would there be any recommendations to handle such an application, to reduce pause times. Unfortunately, this application also serves user requests, so I can't afford large pauses (I know they should ideally be separated, but assuming they can't).

Comment: Well, when all your requirements lock you into a prison cell; then there is not so much what you can do about that; unless you give up on some of the requirements.

Comment: That does not seem to violate the weak generational hypothesis. You may have some objects living for 10 minutes, so they might bleed into the old gen, but that does not preclude the existence of shorter-lived objects. All it means is you will need an old gen GC after 10 minutes.

Comment: Your personal definition of “long running (5-10mins)” is meaningless. Either, there are still shorter living objects, as @the8472 suggested, or, if there are really no objects with a shorter life time, the “5-10mins” *is* the “short living” time of your application. “short” is just the time between minor gc and if a thread works on objects for ten minutes without creating more objects, it won’t trigger a gc for ten minutes. Btw., long spaces do not imply long gc pauses. The pause time depends on the amount of *surviving* objects only. A large space full of dead objects has almost no gc costs.